# WPF Validation ErrorTemplate errorcontent tooltip not working

Tags: wpf, data-binding, app.xaml

I'm not sure if I'm missing something simple or not. I'm thinking maybe a binding needs to change possibly? Or maybe its not properly targeting the TextBox for the ErrorContent?

I think it's worth noting that neither example produces a binding error.

If I have the below XAML defined in my App.xml, when my field is validated, everything looks like it should be working, but the tooltip is not working because ErrorContent seems to be blank, if I change that binding in the tooltip to "Test" the tooltip shows "Test".

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Image
                        Height="24"
                        Margin="-28,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                        Source="/Resources/error-96.png"
                        ToolTip="{Binding /ErrorContent}" />
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image: Screenshot of field validation tooltip not working]

If I add to that same XAML some triggers to set the border colors etc, the tooltip then magically starts working, seen below.

```
<Style BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}" TargetType="TextBox">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
                <Border
                    x:Name="border"
                    Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
                    BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
                    BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
                    SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                    UseLayoutRounding="True">
                    <ScrollViewer
                        x:Name="PART_ContentHost"
                        Focusable="false"
                        HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden"
                        VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Hidden" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="True">
                        <Trigger.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="Red" />
                            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="3" />
                        </Trigger.Setters>
                    </Trigger>
                    <MultiTrigger>
                        <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                            <Condition Property="Validation.HasError" Value="false" />
                            <Condition Property="IsMouseOver" Value="true" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
                        <MultiTrigger.Setters>
                            <Setter TargetName="border" Property="BorderBrush" Value="#FF7EB4EA" />
                        </MultiTrigger.Setters>
                    </MultiTrigger>
                    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled" Value="false">
                        <Setter TargetName="border" Property="Opacity" Value="0.56" />
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
    <Setter Property="Validation.ErrorTemplate">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <DockPanel>
                    <Image
                        Height="24"
                        Margin="-28,0,0,0"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
                        VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
                        DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                        Source="/Resources/error-96.png"
                        ToolTip="{Binding /ErrorContent}" />
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

[image: Screenshot of field validation tooltip working]

Incase you want to see the textbox binding, which works to show the ErrorTemplate.

```
<TextBox
        Margin="0,2.5,2.5,2.5"
        HorizontalAlignment="Stretch"
        ui:ControlHelper.PlaceholderText="IPv4 Address"
        ui:TextBoxHelper.IsDeleteButtonVisible="False"
        Text="{Binding EditServerModel.IPAddress, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
```

My main reason for not wanting to use the second one is it replaces the template of the DefaultTextBoxStyle and breaks the placerholder text in the textboxes, along with some other special features, all I really want/need is the part that shows the error image with a tooltip.

Edit:
I'm using CommunityToolkit.MvvM. My models implement ObservableValidator, which implements INotifyDataErrorInfo. My properties in my models use DataAnnotation attributes such as `[Required]` and `[RegularExpression]`

An example:

```
public class ServerModel : ObservableValidator
{
    private string _iPAddress;
    
    [Required]
    [RegularExpression(@"^(?:[0-9]{1,3}\.){3}[0-9]{1,3}$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid IPv4 address.")]
    public string IPAddress
    {
        get => _iPAddress;
        set
        {
            SetProperty(ref _iPAddress, value);
            ValidateProperty(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Edit - Working answer:

I ended up copying the default style from the ModernWpf project and removing `primitives:ValidationHelper.IsTemplateValidationAdornerSite="True"` so that I could use my own validation template.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this binding:

```
ToolTip="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}"
```

It this doesn't work, the issue is related to the `DefaultTextBoxStyle`.

Comment: Changing that I get a binding error now, I don't know if that gives some insight into what's going on, it almost seems like when I don't have the triggers, there is no errorcontent...
Failed to get value. ArgumentOutOfRangeException:'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. (Parameter 'index')'

Comment: After thinking about it some, I think the issue must be something in the template of "DefaultTextBoxStyle" I'm basing my style on, since as soon as I replace the template with my own, it starts to work. I'm just not sure what could be causing it. This is the xaml for that style.
https://github.com/Kinnara/ModernWpf/blob/master/ModernWpf/Styles/TextBox.xaml

Comment: I use INotifyDataErrorInfo, I've updated my answer with an example of how it's used.

Comment: Does if work if you remove `BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultTextBoxStyle}"`?

Comment: It does work.
I copied that style into my app.xaml and started disabling parts of the template until it started working. There is a Border element that has a tag `primitives:ValidationHelper.IsTemplateValidationAdornerSite="True"`. If I remove that tag, then it works. Is there a way to target just that border element in the template and turn that off or do I have to copy the entire template to my code?

Comment: If the attached property is set on an element in the template, you need to define a whole new template. Or find the element in the visual tree programmatically.