# WPF - ErrorTemplate tooltip showing on the Border but not one the TextBox

Tags: wpf, validation, xaml, data-binding, tooltip

I have TextBox controls with a Binding to an integer property. They're like:

```xml
<TextBox x:Name="txtInteger"
         Grid.Row="2"
         Grid.Column="0"
         Text="{Binding Path=IntegerValue}"
         Validation.ErrorTemplate="{StaticResource ValidationForNumericValues}"/>
```

Predictably, `ValidationForNumericValues` is the validation error template:

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationForNumericValues">
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Red">
                <Border.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Placement="Right"
                             HorizontalOffset="5"
                             VerticalOffset="5"
                             Content="Please enter a number"/>
                </Border.ToolTip>
                <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
            </Border>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

When I enter an alphanumeric value in `txtInteger`, the red border duly shows up, but I don't see the tooltip when the mouse cursor is within the `TextBox`. It only shows when the cursor is above the red border.

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71739422/9256002) suggests the `DefaultBoxStyle` might have something to do with it, but removing the `<Style.../>` declaration didn't improve things.

I also tried to use a different control, like

```xml
<Window.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="ValidationForNumericValues">
        <Grid>
            <Border BorderThickness="1"
                    BorderBrush="Red">
                <Border.ToolTip>
                    <ToolTip Placement="Right"
                             HorizontalOffset="5"
                             VerticalOffset="5"
                             Content="Please enter a number"/>
                    </ToolTip>
                </Border.ToolTip>
                <TextBlock Text=""
                           Opacity="100"
                           Foreground="Red"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                    <TextBlock.ToolTip>
                        <ToolTip Placement="Right"
                                 HorizontalOffset="10"
                                 VerticalOffset="10"
                                 Content="Please enter a number"/>
                    </TextBlock.ToolTip>
                </TextBlock>
            </Border>
            <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
        </Grid>
    </ControlTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

This lets the tooltip show up on the `TextBox`'s whole surface... but I can't set the focus on it by clicking on it. I understand the `TextBlock` blocks it; I'd have thought that placing it before the `AdornedElementPlaceholder` would have put it under the `TextBox`, but I guess since it only appears conditionally, it always appear above.

(I've also tried the same thing with the `TextBlock` declared before the `Border` and the `AdornedElementPlaceholder` inside the `Border`, which I'm not including to save space, and had the same result.)

I've tried

```xml
<AdornedElementPlaceholder>
    <AdornedElementPlaceholder.ToolTip>
        <ToolTip Placement="Right"
                 HorizontalOffset="5"
                 VerticalOffset="5">
            <TextBlock>Please enter a number</TextBlock>
        </ToolTip>
    </AdornedElementPlaceholder.ToolTip>
</AdornedElementPlaceholder>
```

but that doesn't appear to affect the `TextBox`'s `ToolTip` property, just that of `AdornedElementPlaceholder`.

I've tried to bind the `TextBox`'s `ToolTip` property, but I can't figure out how to get to the `Border`'s tooltip `Content`.

(In case it's relevant, I use a .NET 5.0 project under Visual Studio 2019.)

What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give your border a transparent background. A background (or content) is required for anything other than the borderline to be picked up when hit testing.

```
<Border BorderThickness="1"
        BorderBrush="Red"
        Background="Transparent">
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks a lot! (So simple, and yet I hadn't seen it in other examples.)